# Java Android Studio: value changes when I flip the screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

So I am trying to create a quiz game however, whenever I flip my screen around I come across the following issues:
1. When I rotate the screen and it changes to landscape, even if I choose the wrong answer, I get the wrong message but the score still gets incremented. 
2. The question and choices changes rather than staying the same whenever I turn the screen.

here is my code:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class quiz extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4;
    TextView score,question;
    int count=0;
    String text="Wrong";
    private question mq= new question();
    private String manswer;
    private int mScore=0;
    private int mquestionLength= mq.nquestion.length;

    Random r;

    private static final String Sscore="";
    private static final String nums="";
    private String Ques;
    private int num;
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private String arr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.quiz);
        num=0;
        r = new Random();

        answer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        answer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        answer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        answer4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);

        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        score.setText("Score: " + mScore);


        updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mquestionLength));


            answer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onClick(View v) {
                                               num++;
                                               if (answer1.getText() == manswer) {
                                                   mScore++;
                                                   score.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                                                   updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mquestionLength));
                                               }
                                               else {
                                                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                   updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mquestionLength));
                                               }
                                               if(num>8){
                                                   GameOver();
                                               }

                                           }
                                       }
            );
            answer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onClick(View v) {
                                               num++;
                                               if (answer2.getText() == manswer) {
                                                   mScore++;
                                                   score.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                                                   updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mquestionLength));
                                               } else {
                                                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                   updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mquestionLength));
                                               }
                                               if(num>8){
                                                   GameOver();
                                               }


                                           }
                                       }
            );
            answer3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onClick(View v) {
                                               num++;
                                               if (answer3.getText() == manswer) {
                                                   mScore++;
                                                   score.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                                                   updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mquestionLength));

                                               } else {
                                                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                   updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mquestionLength));
                                               }
                                               if(num>8){
                                                   GameOver();
                                               }

                                           }
                                       }
            );
            answer4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onClick(View v) {
                                               num++;
                                               if (answer4.getText() == manswer) {
                                                   mScore++;
                                                   score.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                                                   updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mquestionLength));

                                               } else {
                                                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                   updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mquestionLength));
                                               }
                                               if(num>8){
                                                   GameOver();
                                               }

                                           }
                                       }
            );
        }


        private void updateQuestion ( int nextInt){

           if(count==0) {
               question.setText(mq.getQuestion(nextInt));
               answer1.setText(mq.getChoice(nextInt));
               answer2.setText(mq.getChoice2(nextInt));
               answer3.setText(mq.getChoice3(nextInt));
               answer4.setText(mq.getChoice4(nextInt));

               manswer = mq.getAnswer(nextInt);
           }
           else{
               if(!list.contains(nextInt)){
                   question.setText(mq.getQuestion(nextInt));
                   answer1.setText(mq.getChoice(nextInt));
                   answer2.setText(mq.getChoice2(nextInt));
                   answer3.setText(mq.getChoice3(nextInt));
                   answer4.setText(mq.getChoice4(nextInt));

                   manswer = mq.getAnswer(nextInt);
               }
               else{
                   updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mquestionLength));
               }
           }
            list.add(nextInt);
            count++;

        }

    private void GameOver() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(quiz.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Game Over! Your Score is "+mScore).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(
                "NEW GAME", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),quiz.class));
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("EXIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog=alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(Sscore,mScore);
        outState.putInt(nums,num);
        outstate.putIntegerArrayList(arr,list);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mScore=savedInstanceState.getInt(Sscore);
        num=savedInstanceState.getInt(nums);
        score.setText("Score: "+mScore);
        list.addAll(savedInstanceState.getIntegerArrayList(arr));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of the android's apps is when you rotate the screen and you don't set a unice orientation(landscape or portrait) the actual activity is destroyed and recreated again.

You have 2 options if you want to avoid this:

- you can add on the manifest on the activity the following attribute :

  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
- You can set the orientation of the activity or the all the app with this:

  android:screenOrientation="portrait"

  or

  android:screenOrientation="landscape"

Answer (score 0):

Your code behaves unexpected because you use `onRestoreInstanceState` which is called long after `onCreate` in the lifecycle.
But you do all your important stuff already in `onCreate`.
As far as I know, `onRestoreInstanceState` is called *after onStart*.

You have two options:

1) do your stuff in a private method that you call from `onCreate` **and** `onRestoreInstanceState` (not-so-good)

2) you can simply use the `savedInstanceState` parameter directly in `onCreate`. It contains the bundle you saved in the `onSaveInstanceState` callback. (better)

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle instanceState) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(instanceState);
   instanceState.putString("your_first_value", value1);
   instanceState.putString("your_second_value", value2);
   // ... save all your variables you want to keep ...
}
```

Then, later, when the activity is re-created you get this bundle you just saved supplied in the `savedInstanceState` parameter:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(...); // This creates your controls

    //  if savedInstanceState is not null, you have a saved state here...
    // so you can restore it
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        value1 = savedInstanceState.getString("your_first_value");
        value2 = savedInstanceState.getString("your_second_value");
        // ... here you restore all your values ...
    }
}
```